# JEST Global Variable isn't updated as expected

Tags: javascript, jestjs

When I try with the following code

script.js

```
var aMyVar = [];

[...]

async function load(bHard){     
    console.log(aMyVar);    
    [...]
}

[...]

module.exports = {  
    load
}
```

script.test.js

```
const {
    load
} = require('../script.js');

[...]

describe('My Block', function () {
    test('My Test', async () => {
        global.aMyVar = [{"Key":"Test"}];
        await load(true);  
        [...]
    });
});
[...]
```

Expected behaviour: console.log prints "[{"Key":"Test"}]"

Observed behaviour: console.log prints "[]"

What's wrong?

Comment: What is oJSONSpaceSeq? Did you mean aMyVar? Then the expectation is wrong. aMyVar is local variable and cannot be accessed outside the module.

Comment: I was inconsequent in renaming. Sorry. Fixed it. aMyVar it is - everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) package to modify the variables declared in the module scope.

E.g.

`script.js`:

```js
var aMyVar = [];

async function load(bHard) {
  console.log(aMyVar);
}

module.exports = { load };
```

`script.test.js`:

```js
const rewire = require('rewire');
const mod = rewire('./script');

describe('My Block', function() {
  test('My Test', async () => {
    mod.__set__('aMyVar', [{ Key: 'Test' }]);
    await mod.load(true);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/63676669/script.test.js
  My Block
    ✓ My Test (7ms)

[ { Key: 'Test' } ]
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.842s, estimated 10s
```